# Use value of column as table name in subquery mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am new to mysql I am trying to to create a query where the subquery table name is based in value of column name

I got three table as sample only can be more
first table named main

```
Main

id tbl  val
1   t     2
2   r     1


Next table named t
name
ana
jjj


Next table named r

name
ana
hyu

Desired out put 
I tried this query but not working sql syntax erro

id tbl  val  test
1   t     2  exist
2   r     1  not


Select id, tbl, val, @tblname := tbl, 

isnull((select 'exist' from @tblname where name="jjj" limit 1), "not") as test

from main
```

will really appreciate any advise or help thank you

Comment: Yeah.  What is your question?  Are you learning that table names cannot be replaced with parameters?  To do what you want, you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: thank you for responding to my question really appreciate your time I am new to mysql and queries. 
Can I use the variable name  or column vslue ss table name in my subquery is it possible? sorry dynamic sql is?